# Update value in MySQL via AJAX/PHP when a dynamically created checkbox is clicked?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am creating an admin panel for a project that I am working on. It will list a bunch of entries in a table and each row will have a checkbox in it. This checkbox will be used to activate an entry to be displayed on the website.

I am setting the `id` and `name` of the checkbox with data from the MySQL database. For example..

```
<input type="checkbox" class="active" name="active<?php echo $id; ?>" id="active<?php echo $id; ?>" <?php if ($active == 1): ?>checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

For the entry with ID of 5 it will look like this..

```
<input type="checkbox" class="active" name="active5" id="active5" checked="checked" value="5">
```

I need to set this up so that when you check a box or uncheck it that it updates the "active" value in the database. How do I grab the value of each checkbox, when clicked, and send that value to the MySQL database. I can do this easily if I know the checkboxes `name` beforehand, but since the `name` is partly generated from the database I'm not sure how to write the code to determine which entry gets the active value.

**Here is my jQuery..**

```
$("input.active").click(function() {
// store the values from the form checkbox box, then send via ajax below
var check_active = $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
var check_id = $(this).attr('value');

console.log(check_active);
console.log(check_id);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://nowfoods.marketspacecom.com/nextstep/ajax.php",
        data: {id: check_id, active: check_active},
        success: function(){
            $('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});

        }
    });
return true;
});
```

**Here is the PHP..**

```
<?php

include("dbinfo.inc.php");
mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database"); 

// CLIENT INFORMATION
$active = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['active']);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

$addEntry = "UPDATE entries SET active = '$active' WHERE id = '$id'";
mysql_query($addEntry) or die(mysql_error());


mysql_close();
```

?>

[image: Screenshot of what I am building]

Comment: Please don't use the ancient mysql_* functions anymore, the community has started the deprecation process. Use mysqli or PDO instead!!

Comment: You're open to SQL injection!

Comment: Take a look at this. This uses text boxes and isn't exactly what you're trying to do, but it still involves querying the database upon an input via ajax. Maybe this will clear it up a bit. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class to the input and set the value to the id instead:

`<input class="active" type="checkbox" name="active5" id="active5" value="5" checked="checked">`

Then, change your jQuery:

```
$("input.active").click(function() {
// store the values from the form checkbox box, then send via ajax below
var check_active = $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
var check_id = $(this).attr('value');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://nowfoods.marketspacecom.com/nextstep/ajax.php",
        data: {id: check_id, active: check_active}
        success: function(){
            $('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});

        }
    });
return true;
});
```

As for PHP:

```
<?php

include("dbinfo.inc.php");
mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database"); 

// CLIENT INFORMATION
$active        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['active']);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

// WHERE id=16 is just for testing purposes. Need to dynamically find which checkbox was checked and use that info to tell the query which ID to update. 
$addEntry  = "UPDATE entries SET active = '$active' WHERE id = '$id'";
mysql_query($addEntry) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close();
?>
```

This should be what you're looking for. There may be some minor syntax issues, because I'm writing this off the top of my head, but I hope you get the general idea. :-)

Comment: Ok, I've tried this, but when I click on a checkbox the box does not change to being checked or unchecked and the value in the database does not update. I kind of think the value in the database is not being updated because the checkbox does not change. Not really sure what is causing this.

Comment: Also, is the jQuery part written inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: `return true;` fixed the problem with the checkbox not updating, but the active value did not update in my database.

Comment: Its still not updating the active value in the database. If I manually set the $id to 16 then 16's active value will change no matter what checkbox I'm clicking. Seems like something it getting screwed up in `WHERE` part of the query or PHP.

Comment: Check if data is arriving properly (use Firebug). Also, re-check the codes I've given - there may be some small syntax issues. I doubt that there's a problem with the query itself, because you said it works when you hard-code the id, so I suspect that the AJAX part is acting up somewhere.

Comment: I am stumped. No idea why the `id` value is not working. I'm logging the `check_id` value to the console and it looks good. No clue where or what the problem is when trying to put it into my query :(  I am going to update my code in my post right now.

Comment: I got it.. this line just needed a comma at the end. SMH lol.  Thanks for all your help!!

`data: {id: check_id, active: check_active},`

Comment: Haha, I told you to do syntax checking. :) Glad I've helped.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
var active = $('#active').attr('value');
```

You need to check the clicked element and you have to check whether it is checked or not (the value doesn't really matter that much unless you use it to pass the ID):

```
var active = $(this).is(':checked');    // the checkbox is checked (boolean)
```

You can set it to an integer value like:

```
var active = $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
```

Which is short for:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  var active = 1;
} else {
  var active = 0;
}
```

And in php you need process you user input correctly:

```
$active = (int) $_POST['active'];
```

**Edit:** It seems you have a space that should not be there in your edited code, does it work when you set:

```
...
data: {"active=": check_active, "id": check_id},
...
```

Also, as both values are integers / should be integers, there is no real use escaping them for the database using a string function, you should test for integers or at the very least cast them to integers:

```
// CLIENT INFORMATION
$active = (int) $_POST['active'];
$id = (int) $_POST['id'];
```